# HTML/CSS: Absolute Positioning

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position

I am using `position: absolute;` so my div can be placed at the bottom, but I also need to use `float: left;` so that each new div will be placed next to it, but they are just being placed in the same spot, any suggestions?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <style type="text/css">

        .media_container{
                min-width:  800px; max-height: 800px; 
                min-height: 300px; max-height: 300px;
                border: 2px solid #f00; 
                position: relative;
                }

        .media_header{
                min-width:  220px; max-width:  220px;
                min-height: 50px; max-height: 50px;
                border: 2px solid #f00;
                float: left;
                /*position: absolute;*/
                margin-left: 30px;
                bottom: 30px;
                }

    </style>
  <title>Test</title>
</head>


<body>

  <div class='media_container'>

    <div class='media_header'>Header 1</div>
    <div class='media_header'>Header 2</div>
    <div class='media_header'>Header 3</div>

  </div>

 </body>]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/HeAXf/)

In order to float divs at the bottom of the webpage, your container needs to be set `absolute` and placed at the `bottom`.

Then, all contents in this container are `relative` along with your float requirements. Done!

```css
.media_container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 800px;
  max-height: 800px;
  min-height: 300px;
  max-height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid #f00;
}
.media_header {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  min-width: 220px;
  max-width: 220px;
  min-height: 50px;
  max-height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid #f00;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If all the divs have the same `position:absolute` attribute then they are all going to overlap.

Have a parent div for the divs that you want to show at the bottom. And style this parent div with `position:absolute` and `bottom:0`

Heres the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5GMrj/). I hope this is what you want.